# Windows Alert Shared Network Drive Issue

Tags: windows, file-sharing

I am trying to connect to a network drive and I am getting this MS Windows alert saying

"Not enough server storage is available to process this command."

What does this mean?

Comment: What OS is running on the *sharing* computer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does **not** mean that your server is out of disk space.

It does usually mean that your server is running out of file handles or kernel memory to process clients.  See:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285089/

With the release of Windows 2003 Server SP1, [DEP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/875352) [is enabled on supported systems](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2005/07/05/407330.aspx).  [PAE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/900524) is required for DEP.  The result of this is that on just about any server running SP1 or later, the ammount of kernel memory available is dramatically reduced:

Please reference [this chart](http://blogs.technet.com/clint_huffman/archive/2007/10/01/indentify-32-bit-kernel-memory-issues.aspx)

- 2GB RAM, No PAE, Non-paged pool: 262MB
- 2GB RAM, PAE (required by DEP), Non-paged pool: 131MB

This article is also very detailed in regards to the kernel memory tuning which can help greatly to resolve this error:

http://support.microsoft.com/?id=304101

Comment: In case it isn't clear, I strongly encourage people to use the recommendations in the DEP link to disable DEP and PAE on any system that doesn't require it because of the kernel memory issues it creates.

Answer (score 0):

http://brickblog.net/2009/03/04/not-enough-server-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command%E2%80%9D-error-print-this-post-print-this-post